# Obj-c Binding: Type MonoTouch.UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in interface list is not an interface

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm creating my first binding of https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu and everything was going well until I compiled my binding project. The one error I'm getting is that *UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in interface is not an interface*. I can get the binding to compile if I use IUIGestureRecognizerDelegate, but from the looks of the walkthrough, this isn't the correct approach. I came across another SO question regarding this same issue except they were using custom types whereas this is a type that is in the framework and so I'm confused as to why it doesn't compile. What is the correct approach here?

The Objective-C code for the class is:

```
@interface RESideMenu : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

In my ApiDefinition.cs:

```
[BaseType (typeof (UIViewController))]
public partial interface RESideMenu : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a case of merely stating that your class adopts the protocol, you can remove the UIGestureRecogznierDelegate property.  If you need to use "this" as a parameter to something that requires a UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, you can just use the "Weak" version of the property.

For example:

```
 var d = new UIGestureRecognizerDelegate ();
 d.WeakDelegate = new RESideMenu ();
```

Notice the use of "WeakDelegate" instead of "Delegate" there.